# python3-module object is not callable

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

crawl.py. I try to port it to python3. I leave out all unnecessary details.
Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "crawl.py", line 44, in parseAndGetLinks
    self.parser = html.parser(AbstractFormatter(DumbWriter(StringIO())))
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable


import html.parser  
from formatter import DumbWriter, AbstractFormatter  
from io  import StringIO     

parser = html.parser(AbstractFormatter(DumbWriter(StringIO())))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`html.parser` is the module; you want the [`HTMLParser` class](http://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html#html.parser.HTMLParser) *in* that module:

```
parser = html.parser.HTMLParser(AbstractFormatter(DumbWriter(StringIO())))
```

or more succinctly:

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser

parser = HTMLParser(AbstractFormatter(DumbWriter(StringIO())))
```